# Tornado does not set cookie in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cookies, tornado, setcookie

I just tried to use tornado as a backend for my angular 7 web application. At this point I don't know what else to do but Chrome does not seem to even process a `Set-Cookie` header sent with each response. I do all my client server transactions using `withCredentials=true` from angulars side. To test the angular application I use the angular-cli command ng serve, which creates a localhost server with whatever specified port. Tornado runs on localhost as well and port 8888.

As far as I understand it Chrome should take care of setting the cookies the backend has sent. I checked the responses leaving my tornado server using wireshark with each cookie being present in the header as follows

```
user="xxxxxxx"; expires=Thu, 06 Dec 2018 21:15:57 GMT; Path=/
```

However, when I inspect the response using the Chrome dev tools, these headers are missing. Also no cookie is set whatsoever. The only thing I can imagine is that this has something to do with serving from localhost to localhost even though I don't have an explanation as to why this should be the reason.

Maybe anyone of you has an idea what this might be.

Comment: `Set-Cookie` is a response header, not a request header. And when you write "incoming requests", I take it that you mean the responses coming from the server, right? Sometimes Chrome (and FF as well) don't show all the headers in the dev tools. There should a be a `Raw Headers` options in the dev tools which shows all the HTTP headers present in the response.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I mean exactly what you just said. However I know for a fact that the response headers contain a `Set-Cookie` field. The main question is why do Chrome or Firefox simply ignore theae

Comment: It could be possible that some JS code is un-setting or overwriting the cookies. Can you try to set a cookie from a new, simple, Tornado project, without Angluar etc? Just one simple handler to test if browsers are actually ignoring the cookies or it related to JS code.